# To Find a 'Weight' Function on $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, x,y \geq 0\}$ Measuring A-Priori-Given Properties

Tags: real-analysis

I seek a map of $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, x,y \geq 0\}$ into ℝ, the value it yields being a 'weight according as' (x,y) has certain properties (and I'll call it a 'weight' for convenience) - in this instance (and letting $q$ denote *either $x$ or $y$*): greater as the size of both $x$ & $y$ are greater; greater the lesser the difference between $x$ & $y$, & 0 when $q=0$; symmetrical under exchange of $x$ & $y$; and insensitive to small changes in $q$ when $q$ is zero - that the *gradient* of the weight with respect to $q$ be zero when $q=0$. One I have devised is - essentially by translating the function $$r\sin^22\theta$$ into cartesian coordinates - is $$\frac{4x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} ;$$ or, if it is to be used for ordering only, $$\frac{(x^2y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3} .$$ (The numerator is left in the form it is in to show that this is essentially a function of $x^2$ & $y^2$ - and because it would indeed be most economically computed by computing those quantities first & then the rest in terms of them.)

Although this is not a *particularly* complicated expression, I do wonder whether there might be some simpler expression that 'slicklier' explements the a-priori-specified properties; and wondering this is a particular instance of wondering whether *in general* there is a systematic method for, or theory of, finding the simplest & slickest weight explementing a-priori-specified properties ... as I have tended to find, through the various particular instances of this problem that I have grappled, that it is *usually* more difficult than at first expected.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey -- Ah yes ... thanks for that advice ... I always have had this bad habit of getting them confused that I still occasionally lapse into! I've fixed it now anyway. ¶ And another _perennial lapsing_ I have is forgetting to '@' my comments! Apologies please, if you have had two lots of notification of this.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey -- I think I've misunderstood you: I first used the term 'measure' and then changed it to 'metric' very shortly before your comment arrived ... so when I read it, my mind just 'flipped' it into being a pointing-out of the incorrectitude of the word 'measure'. ¶ OK I'll review what I've put then I'll just say "map of X×Y into ℝ having certain properties", or something like that ... for the time-being.